# ArrayList - Creating comparators

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I created an ArrayList that contains references to objects that contain various amounts of data.

I wish to sort the object by certain elements of their data.

I successfully did so using the `collections.sort` along with an anonymous class defining the new comparator.

I was successful in each of the new comparators I created which resulted in correct sorted order.

For the same ArrayList how could you make a comparator that would give the original input of the ArrayList order. I know that the ArrayList saves the order of the objects they are added, insertion order. But after sorting the ArrayList with other comparators, how would I then sort the ArrayList back to the original order that it was in? This is the one thing that is stumping me, and I can't seem to figure it out.

Edit: I should clarify this is for an assignment, in which the instructions say to include a default/original comparator to get the unsorted input. That just doesn't make sense to me, given what we mentioned. The ArrayList will save the insertion order when it is added, but when you sort that it is lost. i don't see how you could create a comparator that will sort what the original list was.

Edit2: I am given an ArrayList which is expected to store a few objects that contain some data elements which will be sorted, such as by their names or their age. This comparators were easy to make and I do so successfully. The assignment also wants to an original comparator that display the data as it was inserted. Now these comparators are being passed in a method call, in which that method will use the collections.sort on each different comparator. It is asking for the original comparator to be used first though.

The idea of the original comparator at all seems illogical. The fact that is being used first, so no other sorting has been done yet makes it seem that it was only made so it fits the argument list of calling the method to display the data. So in other words, I guess the original comparator should just return nothing..?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question as you've posted it. The first half seems completely unrelated to the second half. Previous ordering is lost after a sort so there is no way to go back to the insertion order because nothing tracks that. If you need that tracked, literally do so by not sorting your array but by creating a list copy and sorting that, preserving the original list.

Comment: Clone your ``ArrayList`` before sort to store the state; and you could used that clone copy later.

Comment: if it's a homework question, show the exact phrasing, don't describe it in your own words. However, be aware of the [how do I ask homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) thread, because homework questions are often contrived and sometimes nonsense to people who make a living, try to, or used to, with the language you're asking questions for (this feels like one in the nonsense category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is asking for the original comparator to be used first though.

This means that the comparator doesn't need to *restore* the original order, which is what wouldn't make any sense (impossible), but to do *nothing* when used to sort, i.e. leave the original order *unchanged*.

Quoting javadoc of [`sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

This means that if you pass in a comparator that claims all objects to be equal, no reordered will take place.

```
// Java 8 example using lambda expression
Collections.sort(list, (a,b) -> 0); // No-op. All elements compare equal
```

Comment: Yeah I believe this is the correct approach and is what I ended up doing( I just returned 0). The way it was worded seemed like it wanted to restore the order, I thought I had a misunderstanding or missed something entirely as it made no sense. But the way the initial program is structured before I finished it isn't so much on 'restoring the order'.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from making a clone (commented above) would be for the object to contain a separate field that tracks order inserted into the array and write a comparator for that.

Comment: Yeah sadly neither of which are allowed in my circumstance. I think it's just a space holder so the method can be called as it expects a comparator to be passed. It can't be anything else..

Comment: then you're likely stuck with cloning the original collection